# How to update value in Autoform Placeholder

Tags: javascript, mobile, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have a form where I want to update user information. I want to provide the update form with current user data located in placeholder. This data will be provided using a routecontroller. However it does not work. I was wondering if there is any solution to this.

```
{{> afFieldInput name='age' placeholder={{age}}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{> afFieldInput name='age' placeholder=age }}`

That should work. But this would populate the value of age by default (if already present) and only when the user deletes the value would the placeholder text show.